# SSIS - how to import csv with only 1 text qualifier

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

I'm using SSIS and trying to import a csv file.  However, only 1 field has a text qualifier - double quotes " - which in turn also contains commas.  Even if I specify the " as a qualifier, SSIS seems to ignore this and still splits the data into the next field - is there a solution or do all columns need the qualifier for it to work?

This is an example of the data:

```
Field1,    Field2,    Field3,       Field4
ABC,        123,       "QWER,ASD",  ZXC
```

So when I import at the moment, SSIS is splitting Field3, even though I have specified " as a text qualifier - why is this?

I am defining the text qualifier thus:
[image]

Comment: @Larnu defo defining the text qualifier - updated post

Comment: Does your file *really* have those leading white spaces? If so, it's malformed. A properly text qualified value with leading spaces should be `"       QWER,ASD"`. If those leading spaces shouldn't be there, you need to remove them, as your file isn't a well formed CSV file.

Comment: no, it does not have leading white spaces, just added them for readability

Comment: ... Don't; that isn't a valid CSV file anymore. YOu also have a trailing comma at the end of your header row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your file, it's malformed. You have leading spaces prior to your values (        `123`) and a mismatch of columns in your rows; the header has 5 columns and the data row 4 columns. For a value to be correctly text qualified the qualifier must be at the **start** of the value:
`"       QWER,ASD"` Correct
       `"QWER,ASD"` Incorrect

You need to fix your file first. Presumably you don't want the leading spaces, so it should look like this:

```
Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4
ABC,123,"QWER,ASD",ZXC
```

Then SSIS works as you expect it to:
[image]
[image]

If you *do* want the leading spaces (in the values and column names) it should look like this:

```
Field1,    Field2,    Field3,       Field4
ABC,        123,"       QWER,ASD",  ZXC
```

Which also works as you would "expect":
[image]